# Jsoup traverse one by one

Tags: html, jsoup

I have to iterate over the html content of each div one by one.

```
<div class="category">      <a href="some url">1</a>    </div>
<div class="category">      <a href="some url">2</a>    </div>
<div class="sub-category">  <ul><li></li>....</ul>      </div>
<div class="category">      <a href="some url">4</a>    </div>
<div class="sub-category">  <ul><li></li>....</ul>      </div>
<div class="category">      <a href="some url">6</a>    </div>
```

I have tried

```
element.select("div.category")
element.select("div.sub-category")
```

it fetches data but not in sequence.

I just want to fetch one category then its sub-category. Also note that some category don't have sub-categories.

Kindly suggest anyone, the proper way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Does `element.select("div.category, div.sub-category")` do the trick for you? You will get every single div, both category and sub-category class.

Comment: Hi , is the subcategory children of category ?

Comment: No each are distinct, but all are children of one node say <div class="menu">

Answer (score 0):

You can use these syntaxes:

```
[attr^=value]: for elements with attributes that start with value
[attr$=value]: end with value
[attr*=value]: contain the value
```

In your case: "category" & "sub-category" both contain the substring "category" and end with "category" therefore you can use:

```
.select("div[class*=category]") or
.select("div[class$=category]")
```

Comment: Thanks Eritrean, for your reply. The above example is just to explain my problem. The actual website in which I am working ,have no matching class/id names for the parent and child nodes. And if I use some part of the class name inside .select (option 3 of ur example), it may fetch other node contents those have similar class name which are not required for my output.